# Spring Batch Call DAO Class From Listener Class

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I am very new to Spring. i am using spring batch to execute a job. I have configured everything and it is working fine.
But i have one problem. From xml configuration i am calling JobListener class to update batch start information.

From xml config i can able to able call JobListener and initialize datasoure and jobID. But i need to call class called JobDAO from JobListener class to insert batch status.
Is there any possible to configure in xml or i need to create object for JobDAO class and to call it.

Sorry for this kind of question. Kinldy help me.

```
<batch:job id="txn-det" >
    <batch:step id="step1">
        // Item reader & Item writer
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>         

<bean id="jobListener" class="com.JobListener" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jobID" value="TXN01"/>
</bean>
```

JobListener.java

```
public class JobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    String jobID = null;

    @Autowired
    JobDAO jobDAO = null;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void setjobID(String jobID)  {
        this.jobID = jobID;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        startTime = new Date();
        System.out.println("Job starts at :"+startTime);
        // TODO Call DAO to insert Job status
        jobDAO.logJobStatus(); // Null pointer is throwing here 

    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try like this.

In JobListener.java

```
@Autowired
JobDAO jobDAO = null;

@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    startTime = new Date();
    System.out.println("Job starts at :"+startTime);
    jobDAO.log()

}
```

From XML Config :

```
<bean id="jobListener" class="com.JobListener" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jobID" value="TXN01"/>
        <property name="jobDAO" ref="jobDAO" />
</bean> 

<bean id="jobDAO" class="com.JobDAO" />
```